# All pages redirect to homepage after .htaccess changes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a Wordpress site that I'm trying to test live, so I've changed my .htaccess file to redirect all pages to a maintenance page for everyone except me (based on my IP). Here are my rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=307,L]

</IfModule>
```

This works as intended: everyone sees the maintenance page except me. The problem is only the homepage is working for me: every other link results in a 404 error. What should I do to see the whole site working?

By the way, the site is hosted on a Dreamhost VPS server that uses Ubuntu.

Comment: If you remove the .htaccess file, does the problem definitely go away for you?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the rules as follows fixed it for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^151\.42\.160\.116
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html [R=307,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I guess once you've redirected everyone else to the maintenance page, you still need more rewrite rules so that the site can function properly for you.